# PHP ORM with full composite primary/foreign key support

Tags: php, orm, key, relationship, composite

I'm looking for PHP5 ORM which fully supports composite (multi-column) relations based on composite primary keys and foreign keys.

I hoped that Doctrine 2 would solve this problem but it doesn't. It's a basic feature in relational data modelling but none of PHP ORM software I know supports it.

I've recently found that SQLAlchemy has full support but I need something for PHP, not Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine 2.1 solves this problem completely.

Answer (score 4):

When you're approaching the application from the database perspective something like Doctrine2 (PHP) or Hibernate (Java) from which it is "derived", is not appropriate. These are much more suited when you want to go the other way around (i.e. "I have an OO domain model and need to persist it in a relational db", not "I have a relational db and want a (generated?) OO interface for it, without making any compromises whatsoever on the database side"). If you use them despite this important differences in the approaches and you love your relational schema more than your object model you will just get frustrated.

It is really important to differentiate between different categories of ORM tools as they tend to focus on different development models.

Maybe try out Propel or RedBeanPHP, which seem suited for a database-driven development model with almost no mapping going on, just plain generated (and usually dumb) "data objects" and not much abstraction. Foreign key fields are just put into objects directly in these solutions, etc. so they might "support" all the composite stuff you want.

Solutions like Doctrine2 or Hibernate discourage use of composite keys and hence only support them up to a certain level (Hibernate goes pretty far but nevertheless they are not recommended to use).

Personally I'm not a fan of composite keys (with the exception of pure many-to-many link tables with no additional data) because I tend to approach things much more from the application/domain-model/object side and there composite keys that are mapped to objects are often a pain to work with, even if the underlying mapping technology supports them. Surrogate keys (or at least single-field natural keys) make things much simpler. I'm not a relational-database-normalization-fetishist and the "better performance" is highly questionable from my point of view. Saving an occasional join won't save you if you have real performance problems in a system.

Comment: Please don't mention Hibernate. It is more than capable to create domain model from database, especially composite keys.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, but in my point of view relational data model is much more important than application. I know systems with databases older than 25 years (without crucial changes) - and their application front-ends changed dozens of times completely. Changing an application is very easy - changing or tuning bad data design is very difficult or sometimes impossible without re-adding half of data. That's why i think that software development should be data focused not application focused - and that's why I look for an database-driven ORM.

Comment: @jpartogi: In my eyes you can never create a (good) domain model by reverse-engineering a relational database, and it is discouraged to use composite keys with Hibernate as well. Quoting from the documentation: "There is an alternative <composite-id> declaration that allows access to legacy data with composite keys. Its use is strongly discouraged for anything else." I know it has strong support for it but mostly for legacy databases.

Comment: @jpartogi: I mentioned Hibernate since it is the same approach: Encouraging an object-centric development model and discouraging composite keys.

Answer (score 0):

From Doctrine2 reference:

> Doctrine 2 allows to use composite
>   primary keys. There are however some
>   restrictions opposed to using a single
>   identifier. The use of the
>   @GeneratedValue annotation is only
>   supported for simple (not composite)
>   primary keys, which means you can only
>   use composite keys if you generate the
>   primary key values yourself before
>   calling EntityManager#persist() on the
>   entity.
>
> To designate a composite primary key /
>   identifier, simply put the @Id marker
>   annotation on all fields that make up
>   the primary key.

Comment: Nope, your information is useless. Even Doctrine 1 supports composite primary keys. I need multi-column relations based on composite primary key and composite foreign key. Doctrine 2 reference says that it doesn't support that here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/limitations-and-known-issues/en#limitations-and-known-issues

Comment: yes, sorry, you are right, I havent seen that. I was working with v1.2

Comment: I'm also using Doctrine v1.2 now. In such cases I create ugly surrogate-keys which emulate needed feature... but it spoils good relational data design and ends up in lower performance (unnecessary indexes)

Comment: Composite keys are something there is some debate around about. For example, Ruby-on-Rails does not support composite primary keys at all.

Comment: But who says that Ruby-on-Rails has good ORM? Properly used composite keys allow much better database design and better performance (sometimes it allows to omit JOINs which are one of biggest bottle necks in queries).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [LEAP ORM](http://orm.spadefoot.com), which is written in PHP 5.  It is available on github at https://github.com/spadefoot/kohana-orm-leap.

The Leap ORM fully supports composite keys, both for primary keys and foreign keys.  Likewise, it works with non-integer primary/foreign keys.  Within the ORM models, you can create field alias, field adapters, and relations.

Although it is written for the [Kohana PHP Framework](http://kohanaframework.org/), you can easily make it work with any PHP framework by just adding a simple autoload function to you code.  Leap works with the following databases: DB2, Drizzle, Firebird, MariaDB, MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite.  It also provides both a query builder and a database connection pool.

On the ORM's Website, there are a lot of good [examples and tutorials](http://orm.spadefootcode.com/tutorials/index) to help you understand how to use it.